# Rails 6 - what is the proper way to load custom JS files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I struggle to properly configure and set up my own JS files that contain JS functions for specific tasks.

I went through some articles and found that I need to place my custom JS to the JS packs folder -> `app/javascript/packs/currency_calculations.js`:

**currency_calculations.js**:

```
function convert_curr(from, to) {
  ...
}

function show_convertion(curr) {
  ...
}
...
```

and then I try to add this custom JS file to `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage";
import "channels";
import "controllers";

Rails.start();
ActiveStorage.start();

import "stylesheets/application";

// my custom JS file
import "packs/currency_calculations" // I also tried import "currency_calculations" -- same result
```

I also tried to add the following to the **application.html.erb** file:

```
 = javascript_pack_tag 'currency_calculations'
```

It didn't work either.

I am still getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'currency_calculations'
```

and when trying to call a function from a view, then:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: convert_curr is not defined
```

What is the correct way to wire this up? I am used from Rails 5 to put all my JS functions to a js file and this file just to add to a `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` like this:

```
//= require currency_calculations
```

and then, in a view, I am able to simply call the wanted JS function like `convert_curr("a", "b")`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways to do this in Rails 6.

The first would be to create a custom directory and require it in the application.js file. In this case you could create a directory like this:

```
app/javascript/custom/currency_calculations.js
```

Then you would need to require it in your application.js file as such:

```
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

// ...

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("custom/currency_calculations")
```

That same method could also be streamlined if you, say, named your custom folder "currency" and then named the .js file index.js.

You could then just call it like this:

```
require("currency")
```

Require will look for the index file by default in the folder. But in that scenario, an index file must be present, or it will fail.

The other way to do this, in the event you don't want that JS to be compiled with everything else, is to use the javascript_pack_tag.

In that case, add the js file to your app/javascript/packs directory. Then use the  pack tag helper where you need it such as:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'currency_converter' %>
```

The last thing I would mention... are you sure there's no other library needed to make it work (such as JQuery)? In that case you would need to install and import that library to your application.js before you called the js file you're trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not exporting anything in your js file. Try doing this in currency_calculations.js

```
const funcs = {
   convert_curr() { console.log('foo') }, 
   show_convertion() { console.log('bar') },
}

export default funcs;
```

And then in your code you call them with `funcs.convert_curr()`

Also it seems that currency_calculation shouldn't be it's own pack (you can think of a pack kinda like what application.js was in sprockets), so better be just a standalone js file outside the packs dir. (could be `javascript/currency_calculations.js` or `javascript/utils/currency_calculations.j`s)

Answer (score 0):

Some comments that may help you:

1 ) when you put a js file at /packs, it's going to be compiled as a standalone asset you can reference using `javascript_pack_tag`, so you don't need to add it to the `application.js` pack

you have two options depending on what you want:

- move the file to javascript/src/currency_calculations.js and import it in your application.js as `import 'src/currency_calculations'` or `import '../src/currency_calculations'`
- use it as a pack, remove it from application.js and use load it like `javascript_pack_tag 'currency_calculations'`

(you can have the file loaded both in application.js and as a standalone pack, but you'll have the code twice)

2 ) if you want to access the functions from that file in your view, you can't do it just like sprocket does. sprockets adds the content of that file in the global scope while webpacker contains the functions in the bundle context. If you want the functions to be available globally from your views, you have to make them global doing something like

```js
global.convert_curr = function(from, to) {
  ...
}
```

(you can also use `window.convert_curr = ...`)